# What is the value that should go into the consumerParams when using the Swagger API in Jhipster 6.6.0 using Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, jhipster, swagger-ui

I am not sure what value should be used in the swagger api when sampling a consumer, and cannot find any documentation on the jhipster site.

[consumerParams Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3xko.jpg)

Comment: That's your API, no? Jhipster is not a Kafka library. Maybe you should look at the actual API code?